# Moment js check if a certain from and to date is in the current week

Tags: javascript, momentjs

My object has a from and to date, based on these 2 dates I need to check if the current week falls in that range but I am a bit stuck.

I made this function to get the current week using moment js:

```
function getCurrentWeek() {
    var currentDate = moment();

    var weekStart = currentDate.clone().startOf('week');
    var weekEnd = currentDate.clone().endOf('week');

    var days = [];

    for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        days.push(moment(weekStart).add(i, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
    }

    return days;
}
```

This returns an array of the current week:

```
["2020-02-09", "2020-02-10", "2020-02-11", "2020-02-12", "2020-02-13", "2020-02-14", "2020-02-15"]
```

Now how can I validate if the current week falls in the from and to date?

```
from: 2020-02-03
to: 2020-02-24
```

Comment: Unless we have different definitions of "current"... Just check if <today> is between `from` and `to`?

Comment: but I need to make a difference between current week and next week. if the user selects filter next week i need to show only the items with ranges that falls in next week and same for current week

Comment: You can also use moment's isSameOrAfter() and isSameOrBefore() to identify if date  falls in given start and end date

Comment: how do I check if today is between from and to?

Comment: So your question (or better requirement) is not complete...

Answer (score 1):

```
function isBetween(from, to){
     let today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
     let afterFromDate = moment(today).isSameOrAfter(from)
     let beforeToDate = moment(today).isSameOrBefore(to)
     if(afterFromDate && beforeToDate){
        return true
     }
     return false
}
console.log(isBetween(from, to))
```

Comment: I did it like this using moment: `moment(currentDate).isBetween(product.available_from, product.available_to)`this is good for current week but how do I check for next week?

Comment: you can add 7 days to current date and check if it is in range. `let dayInNextWeek = moment().add(7, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD')`

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your question, you need to know if a week falls into a date interval?
If so, assuming you have dateInterval as this

```
const dateInterval = {
    from: new Date('2020-02-03'),
    to: new Date('2020-02-03')
};
```

you can input it into this method

```
function isWeekFallsIntoInterval (anyDateOfTheWeek, dateInterval) {
    const startOfWeek = moment(anyDateOfTheWeek).startOf('week').toDate();
    const endOfWeek = moment(anyDateOfTheWeek).endOf('week').toDate();

    return moment(startOfWeek).isSameOrAfter(dateInterval.from) &&
        moment(endOfWeek).isSameOrBefore(dateInterval.to);
}
```

If you just want to know if the week overlaps with the dateInterval, you can use this method:

```
function doesWeekOverlapWithInterval (anyDateOfTheWeek, dateInterval) {
    const startOfWeek = moment(anyDateOfTheWeek).startOf('week').toDate();
    const endOfWeek = moment(anyDateOfTheWeek).endOf('week').toDate();

    return moment(dateInterval.from).isBetween(startOfWeek, endOfWeek, null, '[]') ||
        moment(dateInterval.to).isBetween(startOfWeek, endOfWeek, null, '[]');
}
```